# Is there a "developer image" I can load in a VM?

Tags: linux, eclipse, virtual-machine, vi

I'm looking for a developer image of CentOS (or choose your linux distro), that's maintained similar to BackTrack (http://www.backtrack-linux.org/), in the sense that when the latest version of Eclipse is out, it's installed on the image..

Anyone have any ideas?  I've looked at http://bitnami.com/ bit didn't really come up with anything.

Ultimately, a group of us are doing a hackathon, and we need some standard loaded images for folks who show up at our event.

Thanks!

Comment: why not just get any image you want update eclipse and repackage it?

Comment: Well it would be nice to Eclipse, gcc, java, maven, ivy, python, ruby, etc and know that when eclipse updates, the packaged distro will put out a packaged update.

Comment: there may be a way to script it to ping the server and when there is an update build a new vm with the updated version, but I don't readily know of any that do that.

Comment: I think you tagged this in "vi" accidentally.

Comment: Suppose I should have tagged it as "vim".. Never used vim or emacs to develop before?  It's not always on every linux system you install.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides Pre-Built Developer VMs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

They come in flavors of Database App, Enterprise Java Development, Linux 6 Admin, etc

(Downside.. Most everything is from the Oracle stack)

There is also this: https://www.developervms.com/